# Overlapping macros

Tags: vba, excel, merge

First of all I am sorry for the long post and thank you very much in advance! I have been working on a project and so far I have two macros which only one of them is functioning and the other one is not because, I believe, of an overlap.

sooo the first macro hides some specific rows (and columns but that is not my issue) when a case is selected from a drop-down list;

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
      Select Case Target.Text
      Case "Case 1"
          ActiveSheet.Range("K:W").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
          ActiveSheet.Rows("5:150").EntireRow.Hidden = True
          ActiveSheet.Range("K:K").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
          ActiveSheet.Range("L:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
          ActiveSheet.Range("M:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
          ActiveSheet.Range("N:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
          ActiveSheet.Range("O:O").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
          ActiveSheet.Rows("5:50").EntireRow.Hidden = False
      Case "Case 2"
          ActiveSheet.Range("K:W").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
          ActiveSheet.Rows("5:150").EntireRow.Hidden = True
          ActiveSheet.Range("P:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
          ActiveSheet.Range("Q:Q").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
          ActiveSheet.Range("R:R").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
          ActiveSheet.Range("S:S").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
          ActiveSheet.Range("T:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
          ActiveSheet.Rows("51:100").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

This macro works alright. The second macro I have is (which I got it through stackoverflow :) ) to merge C2 and C3 if there is an "update" value below the "new" entry.
;

```
     C      D
1   LOW     new
2   HIGH    new
3          update
4   Low     new
5          update
6          update
```

and this is the macro;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()
Dim RgToMerge As String
Dim i As Double
For i = 5 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    RgToMerge = ""
    If LCase(Cells(i, 4)) <> "update" Or (LCase(Cells(i + 1, 4)) <> "new" And Cells(i + 1, 4) <> "") Then
    Else
        RgToMerge = "$C$" & Cells(i, 3).End(xlUp).Row & ":$C$" & i
        With Range(RgToMerge)
            .merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

This code works perfectly IF there are no hidden rows.
Now the problem is; if the second case is selected on the first macro, rows from 5 to 50 will hidden. At this point, whenever second macro gets activated, it merges all the C column in one (including the hidden rows).

Is there anyway to rewrite this two scripts to make them work together?

Comment: I think the simplest solution would be to show the rows again, do the merging and then hide them again. At least that woult be approach, but maybe there is a more "cleaner" solution

Comment: Do both of these Worksheet_Change macros sit within the same worksheet code module?

Comment: No, hiding the rows script is in Module 1 and the other case macro is in sheet objects ( there are several sheets ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have tou try this (avoid hidden rows)?  :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()
Dim RgToMerge As String
Dim i As Double
For i = 5 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    If ActiveSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden <> False Then
    Else
        RgToMerge = ""
        If LCase(Cells(i, 4)) <> "update" Or (LCase(Cells(i + 1, 4)) <> "new" And Cells(i + 1, 4) <> "") Then
        Else
            'I don't know if this would work properly with hidden rows
            RgToMerge = "$C$" & Cells(i, 3).End(xlUp).Row & ":$C$" & i
            With Range(RgToMerge)
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Or this (scan rows, display all, merge, hide these which were hidden)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Th()
ReDim Th(ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)
'Fill array with hidden state of rows
For i = 1 To UBound(Th)
    If ActiveSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden <> False Then
        Th(i) = True
    Else
        Th(i) = False
    End If
Next i
'Display all rows
ActiveSheet.Rows("1:" & UBound(Th)).EntireRow.Hidden = False

'Merge
Dim RgToMerge As String
Dim i As Double
For i = 5 To UBound(Th)
    RgToMerge = ""
    If LCase(Cells(i, 4)) <> "update" Or (LCase(Cells(i + 1, 4)) <> "new" And Cells(i + 1, 4) <> "") Then
    Else
        RgToMerge = "$C$" & Cells(i, 3).End(xlUp).Row & ":$C$" & i
        With Range(RgToMerge)
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
    End If
Next i

'Rehide previously hidden rows
For i = 1 To UBound(Th)
    ActiveSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = Th(i)
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked like a charm even with hidden rows around :)! but it doesn't recognize the change and merge it automatically. I know if I add " Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) ", it will be automatic but I can't use that twice in different macros. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Which changes are not recognized? And if you want to reuse the same merge over and over, you first need to detect merged cells to avoid them. But I don't know how to do that by heart!^^

Comment: the first script you provided works %100 with some hidden rows too but whenever I type "update" to D column, I need to run the script manually in order it to perform the action(merging the cells). and it doesn't give any problems with already merged cells so I guess that part is good :)

Comment: Ok so what you need, is to automate the launching of the merging macro but you already have something in Worksheet_change? Why can't you put both in there?

Comment: I tried to put them in different modules but it gave me error. Placing them under sheet object with "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)" on top worked alright without any problems! Thank you very much R3uK !! :)

Comment: Yup, if it is an event listener as Worksheet_Change(), you need to place it in a specific sheet. But you can call procedure in that Worksheet_Change() that are placed in a module (if you do reference it well (addind sheet name and such))
enjoy